# How to organize the following simple Java code?

Tags: java, android

As a beginner with Java and Android, I understand that Java allows you to write a "clean" code by separating into different files, classes, etc.

Now I have the following working code for an activity that displays my current location:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //
    } else {
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback,
                null /* Looper */);
    }

    mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            if (locationResult == null) {
                return;
            }
            for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                // Update UI with location data
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
                Double latDouble = location.getLatitude();
                String latString = latDouble.toString();
                tv.setText(latString);
            }
        };
    };
}
```

How should I change it so that the MainActivity look cleaner, and that I have most of the code in different files? Do I need to create a new Java Class and then extend it from the Main Activity?

I would like to have a single example of how to arrange my simple code so that it matches the Java conventions. I know it might be silly question but it would help me (and probably more beginners) alot!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't create a separate file just for this amount of code. Sometimes you have to ask yourself what part of the code can be reused in other scenarios, then you could probably organise it in a separate abstract class, a fragment, etc and possibly add it to a module of its own and import it to different projects. Usually, separation or compartmentalisation is used either for improving reusability or readability.

From your code above you could create a method to initialise your location request.

eg.

```
public void initLocationRequest (LocationRequest request, Double millisInterval, Double millisFastestInterval, int priority) {
    request.setInterval(millisInterval);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(millisFastestInterval);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(priority);
}
```

then you would just call it like so:

```
initLocationRequest (10000, 5000, LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

if you had many of these methods that you could reuse in various activities, you could create a class (eg LocationUtils) and add all these methods as *public static*. then from your activities, you would call them:

```
LocationUtils.yourMethodName(yourMethodVariable);
```